# How to Automate the process of getting data from BigQuery into excel using BigQuery excel Connector?

Tags: excel, parameters, google-bigquery, vba

I need help for automating my process for getting data into excel from BigQuery. I used this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udZNmb3QFQI and successfully got the data from BigQuery. Now for the automation process I recorded a macro in excel and got the code generated as follows:

Sub Macro4()

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://bigquery-connector.appspot.com/data", Destination:=Range("$C$8") _
    )

    .Name = "ExternalData_4"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .PostText = _
    "q=[""Query"", ""Enter a query:""]&p=[""Project"",""Enter a project ID:""]&k=[""Key"", ""Enter your Connector Key:""]"
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

End Sub

After assigning this macro to a button in excel the message box asks me again for the Query, Project-ID and Connection string to enter. I don't want to enter each and every time as I have to automate this process for my project using dashboards.Kindly help me pass the parameters(query, connection string and project-id) using the VBA code in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could write all the needed details in Excel cells and refer to them in connection settings? Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udZNmb3QFQI&noredirect=1) (4:06 onwards) for an example. 
Kasia